# Game Center won't show for New Version in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center-leaderboard

Is their a reason why this may happen? I have emailed Apple via the iTunes Connect support link but not had a response.

The Game Center leaderboard has been live since the original version but will not pull through to latest version.

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4973r3cdyg1mes/Screenshot%202017-01-12%2007.06.21.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html Apple kill the Game Center App but still it works online GameKit. Also Game Center going on for developers https://developer.apple.com/game-center/

So the app is no longer avaliable in iphone.

Comment: I haven't lost the GameCenter app from my phone. I cannot add an existing live leaderboard to the GameCenter Feature of a new version within iTunes Connect.

Comment: I have the same problem, i can't find the option to set the leaderboard "live"